# Show posts on front page only

Tags: posts, categories, frontpage

I have a carousel that I want to be posted on the front page only but for some reason the code is not working.

The conditional statement

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>

    <div class="hero">
        <div class="hero-carousel">

            <?php
                $catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name=feature&cat=1&posts_per_page=5' );
                while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
            ?>

            <article>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </article>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The site is on http://modestewebstudio.com/theelement

Comment: What does *not working* mean?

Comment: Seems to be your code is working, but I can see that the problem is related to image sizes to meet your jquery; customizing takes a little time. @zenneson

Comment: Make sure you are using the right conditional https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home#Blog_Posts_Index_vs._Site_Front_Page

Comment: You need to expand your question and provide more information like where the code is and more detail about what you have tried to fix it and why it isn't working.

Comment: The condition that allows the carousel to only be shown on the home page is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is_home()` conditional tag applies to the posts page according to your reading settings or home.php file as opposed to the `is_front_page()` conditional which applies to the page on front according to your reading settings or your front-page.php file, if it exists.

Try changing `is_home()` to `is_front_page()`

As for another possible problem might be, take a look at your query arguments

```
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name=feature&cat=1&posts_per_page=5' );
```

You are using `category_name` and `cat` together in one argument. You cannot do that. You have to use one or the other. So you either have to remove the `category_name` parameter or the `cat` parameter

Comment: Added my answer to yours. A combination of our answers should do the trick. +1

Comment: When I put is_home() the carousel shows on all the post pages. But when I put is_front_page() it doesn't show at all.

Comment: @Zenneson If you only need to display this on page one, change `<?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>` to `<?php if ( is_home() && !is_paged() ) : ?>`